# wxFileName:;Mkdir(Filepath,0777,wxPATH_MKDIR_FULL) is not working in LINUX

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I'm Trying to make a directory with path(eg:`/user01/newpath`) by using `wxFileName::Mkdir` with permission `0777`. But the code is not working in some linux systems which has same specifications as like my system. the problem is after creating `'User01'` folder it is not creating `'newpath'` folder and I observed like `"User01"` folder has a Lock symbol.

syntax which I used is: `wxFileName:;Mkdir(Filepath,0777,wxPATH_MKDIR_FULL) ;`

Please, tell is there any function which will work other than `mkdir`, `wxMKDir`, `wxMKdir`(these also have same problem)??

thanks,

Comment: Do you check the return value of `wxFileName::Mkdir()`? Does it show any errors? It's really supposed to work, if it doesn't return an error but doesn't create a directory, it would be a bug, make sure to [report](http://trac.wxwidgets.org/newticket) it, but you need to provide some way to reproduce it or at least some more details.